# Why i m facing the issue with tflite package when i m using in my file?

Tags: android, flutter, tensorflow, plugins

**pubspec.yaml**

```
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: '>=3.0.5 <4.0.0'


dependencies:

  flutter:

    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2

  firebase_core: ^2.14.0

  firebase_auth: ^4.6.3

  cloud_firestore: ^4.8.3

  intl_phone_number_input: ^0.7.3+1

  fluttertoast: ^8.2.2

  image_picker: ^1.0.1

  firebase_storage: ^11.2.4

  provider: ^6.0.5

  animated_text_kit: ^4.2.2

  shared_preferences: ^2.2.0

  flutter_bloc: ^8.1.3

  path_provider: ^2.0.15

  image_gallery_saver: ^2.0.3

  flutter_share: ^2.0.0

  share_plus: ^7.0.2

  tflite_flutter: ^0.10.1

  firebase_ml_custom: ^0.2.0+3

  tflite: ^1.1.2

  vector_math: ^2.1.4

  augmented_reality_plugin: ^4.0.1

  flutter_native_screenshot: ^1.1.2

  uuid: ^3.0.7

dev_dependencies:

  flutter_test:

    sdk: flutter

  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0

flutter:

  uses-material-design: true

  assets:
    - assets/images/bg.png

    - assets/images/auth.png

    - assets/images/profile.jpeg

    - assets/images/image1.jpg

    - assets/images/image2.jpg

    - assets/images/image3.png
```

**fashion_recommendation.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';

import 'package:tflite_flutter/tflite_flutter.dart';

import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

import 'package:path/path.dart'as path;

import 'dart:io';

class ClothingCategory {

    final String label;

    final String imageUrl;

    ClothingCategory({

        required this.label,

        required this.imageUrl
    });
}


class FashionRecommendation {

    static Future < void > loadModel() async {

        try {

            await TfliteFlutter.close(); // Close any previous models if loaded.

        } catch (e) {

            // Ignore any errors during model closing.

        }

        // Load the model and labels from the app's assets

        String modelPath = 'assets/mobilenet_v2_1.0_224.tflite';

        String labelsPath = 'assets/mobilenet_v2_1.0_224.txt';

        await TfliteFlutter.loadModel(

            model: modelPath,

            labels: labelsPath,

        );

        print('Model loaded successfully');
    }

    static Future < List < ClothingCategory >> generateOutfitRecommendations(XFile image) async {

        List < ClothingCategory > recommendations = [];

        // Convert the image to bytes

        final imageBytes = await image.readAsBytes();

        final directory = await getTemporaryDirectory();

        final imagePath = path.join(directory.path, 'outfit_image.jpg');

        // Save the image to a temporary file

        await File(imagePath).writeAsBytes(imageBytes);

        try {

            // Run the model on the image

            List < dynamic > ? recognitions = await TfliteFlutter.runModelOnImage(

                path: imagePath,

                numResults: 3, // Top 3 recommendations

                threshold: 0.1, // Confidence threshold
            );

            if (recognitions != null && recognitions.isNotEmpty) {

                for (var recognition in recognitions) {

                    String outfitLabel = recognition['label'];

                    String outfitImageUrl = ''; // Replace with the actual image URL for the outfit category
                    recommendations.add(ClothingCategory(label: outfitLabel, imageUrl: outfitImageUrl));
                }

            }

        } catch (e) {

            print('Error generating outfit recommendations: $e');

        }

        return recommendations;

    }

}
```

**Error**

`Undefined name 'TfliteFlutter'`.

Please anyone help me to get rid off this?